# Rails 3 has_many :through naming issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Alright, so here's the deal. I have two tables and a join table since it's a many-to-many relationship. I have an order and an order can have many products. Obviously it goes the other way since products can be on many orders. I've got the following classes:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders_products
  has_many :products, :through => :orders_products
end

class OrderProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders_products
  has_many :orders, :through => :orders_products
end
```

I'm getting a page to display and I'm able to enter stuff and when I go to interact with the products on the saved order via `@order.products` I'm getting the following error:

```
 SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: order_products: SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "order_products" ON "products".id = "order_products".product_id WHERE (("order_products".order_id = 1))
```

My join table is named `orders_products`, but as you can see it's trying to join through `order_products`. My limited knowledge of Rails naming conventions tells me that `orders_products` is the correct way to name it, and then name my model as `OrderProduct`. I'm really pounding my head against a wall on this one.

EDIT: I see that even though it saved my order it and I selected multiple checkboxes it did not save any values in the `orders_products` table, presumably for the same reason as it is erroring now.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`orders_products` is not the correct naming convention for a `has_many :through` relationship--it *is* correct for a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. In a `has_many :through`, the "join" model is not just for joining--it is also its own model that has its own data, that *also happens* to join two other models together.

If your `OrderProduct` model doesn't have any of it's own data, logic, or constraints, then you could use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship instead, remove the model completely, and then your join table is named right. Otherwise, it is named according to regular model naming conventions, namely `order_products`.

Comment: See the [guide for this topic](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association) for an example of a proper `has_many :through` association.

Comment: Ah see, I thought habtm was deprecated.

Comment: However it seems to have fixed my issue, so you get a star. Also, 5 points for an accepted answer :D

Comment: I am seeing elsewhere that if you want any constraints on the data, such as making sure each relationship is unique, you have to use a has_many :through association. So you need this even if the model doesn't have any of it's own data. I am paying the price for having read this post when deciding whether to use HABTM or has_many :through.

Comment: @unclesol updated the answer to hopefully be a bit more clear